# PHP filter string input, cut off all newlines, 1 chars

Tags: php, html, input, filter

I'm writing in PHP!

There's a user string input, and I want to cut off all newlines,1 chars that are more than 1 in a row (avoid `<br /><br />`...).

example:

```
I am a




SPaMmEr!
```

would become:

```
I am a
SPaMmEr!
```

or

```
I am a
.
.
.
.
SPaMmEr!
```

likewise

Comment: what does *1 chars that are more than 1 in a row* mean?

Comment: To escape the HTML tags you can put them in backticks. (`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting all lines is done this way (if you want to catch dos, mac and unix line feeds):

```
$lines = explode("\n", str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $string));
```

Filtering lines with more than one character can be done with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$lines = preg_grep('/^.{2}/', $lines);
```

Or using regular expressions for the complete process:

```
preg_match_all('/^.{2}.*$/', $string, $matches);
$lines = $matches[0];
```

Or if you don't need an array containing all remaining lines, you can remove the unwanted strings with a single call:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^.?$\n/m', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$str = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $str);
```

Where $str is your user input.

**EDIT**:

Sorry, this code will remove all lines regardless, still might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

\n is a valid input for a newline, as well as \r\n and \n\r. Run a Regex or str_replace to replace all combinations of \r and \n with \n and you can use use explode("\n", $string), and check all items of the array for one char or empty one.
You can remove those, or replace it by a single instance of the repeated char, e.g. I use a single newline for a new paragraph, so it would destroy such.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regexp for this:

```
## replace 1 or more new line symbols with single new line symbol
$empty_lines_trimmed = preg_replace('"(\r?\n)+"', "\n", $empty_lines);
```